# Python on keypress ScrolledText.get()

Tags: python, onkeypress

When I press a key and print the text on the ScrolledText, the last key I pressed is not showing in the ScrolledText.get(). Anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's just .bind_all